# How to hide Tabs of Xamarin.Forms's Android app on runtime?

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I'm using XF's appcompat for Android. 
Is there way to hide tabs on runtime? 
Many android uses this feature.

I've spent really long time but couldn't find any way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Xamarin Bug 52374 - IsVisible Doesn't Hide Tabs in TabbedPage](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=52374)

> For now, in order to remove the title and the tab you will have to
>   remove the page from TabbedPage.Children. If using XAML, you may be
>   able to create a bindable property in your children pages that will
>   handle this when the property is changed.